# Php division not working

Tags: php, html, division

For some reason when ever I compile this code, it gives me zero. Why is this?

```
$aou = 5; //Amount of upvotes
$aod = 2; //Amount of downvotes
$elo = (auo/aod) * 150; //Elo
echo "Your elo is: " . $elo;
```

Comment: Missing `$` before variable names: `$elo = ($auo/$aod) * 150; //Elo
`

Comment: If you had errors enabled, you'd have seen warnings about missing constants `auo` and `aod`, which should have given you a clue

Comment: wait one sec, its still not giving me 375

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you type `auo` and `aod` instead of `$auo` and `$aod`. PHP is trying to look up constants of those names, and not variables.

Constants are defined and used without the dollar sign, e.g.

```
const FOO = 123;
echo FOO;
```

But variables need `$` every time you use them, thus

```
$bar = 123;
echo $bar;
```

Comment: Its still not giving me 375 even when I have the $ added

Comment: I get 375 when I tested, but there is a typo in the equation. You have `auo` instead of `aou` in your equation. But *that* has nothing to do with php anymore....